# Making a table out of divs - floating text to be shoulder to shoulder at the center using floats

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Edit-- After doing some research, I stumbled on this link http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di for anyone who's stumped like me trying to make divs behave like tables.

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/06guryqo/

I want the text to be shoulder to shoulder to that centered line. I floated the left column right and right column left. I used clear on the right column, it worked but it pushed my h3 out of place back to the left side so I applied clear on that side and nothing... *scratching my head* I'm hearing tables might be the best way to go about this, but I wanted to try to do this with divs first. I haven't worked with tables at all not know what the pros and cons are.

P.S. Instead of using floats to align content inside the divs, could I use absolute positioning to relative parent. I've been reading that absolute positioning is frowned upon/bad practice when it comes to laying stuff out but in this case of moving content around in table, could it be that bad, and if so why?

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
html {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    background: #666699;
}
#sections {


    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1010px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: #CC6666;
}
#leftSections {
    float: left;
}
#leftSections p,
h3 {


    margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
#rightSections {
    float: right;
}
#rightSections p,
h3 {


    margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
.sectionLfirst {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
.sectionLsecond {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
.sectionLthird {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
.sectionRfirst {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
}
.sectionRsecond {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
}
.sectionRthird {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<div id="sections">
<!--LEFT DIV TABLES-->
<div id="leftSections">
    <div class="sectionLfirst">
         <p>EXPERIENCED CENTERA</p>
         <h3 span style="font-weight:bold";>Align to center   lineeeeeeee</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionLsecond">
         <p>EXPERIENCED CENTERA</p>
         <h3 span style="font-weight:bold";>Align to center lineeeeeeee</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionLthird">
         <p>EXPERIENCED CENTERA</p>
         <h3 span style="font-weight:bold";>Align to center lineeeeeeee</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<!--LEFT SECTION COLUMNS-->
<div id="rightSections">
    <div class="sectionRfirst">
         <p>EXPERIENCED CENTERA</p>
         <h3 span style="font-weight:bold";>Align to center lineeeeeeee</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionRsecond">
         <p>EXPERIENCED CENTERA</p>
         <h3 span style="font-weight:bold";>Align to center lineeeeeeee</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionRthird">
         <p>EXPERIENCED CENTERA</p>
         <h3 span style="font-weight:bold";>Align to center lineeeeeeee</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Luca  Thanks. I will play around that! Eventually I want to turning these into buttons with roll over effects.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to achieve table-like layout without using tables, you can use css `display: table` and related (`table-cell` etc)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

> display: table-cell;
>
> These elements behave like  HTML elements.

Using tables is not necessarily evil - if you are displaying tabular data, then a `<table>` is appropriate. (If you just want to achieve the same layout style, then look into the above css)

Comment: and tips on styling it?  This is horrendous ---> jsfiddle.net/3bmbxcvb using display table. I added border styles and some seems to work.